# cordova InAppBrowser open remote page suport call native method?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I met a problem when trying to open a remote page in cordova.

I tried using the `InAppBrowser` plugin open remote page no call native method.

I checked the official documentation.
`InAppBrowser` does not allow access to local methods, but I need to implement this functionality.

Can you help me get an insight of how can I do this or get an approach of it?

Answer (score 2):

An emulation of the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) has been added to [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) for Android & iOS by [this PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/362) which enables you to post messages from the page loaded into the InappBrowser Webview back to the main Cordova Webview where your app is running. Using this would enable you to call "native methods" in your app from the page loaded into the InappBrowser.

This functionality is not yet in the [latest release version on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) (`v3.0.0`) so you'll need to install the plugin directly off the Github master branch (`v3.1.0-dev`):

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

In your Cordova app code you'd add code to listen for messages from the InappBrowser, for example:

```
var inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("http://www.mypage.com", "_blank");
inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener("message", function (params){
    if(params.data.action === "myNativeMethod"){
        // Call your native method
        myApp.myNativeMethod();
    }
});
```

Then in the webpage being loaded into the InappBrowser you'd send the message:

```
<button id="myButton">Press me</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var message = {action: "myNativeMethod"};
        webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message));
    }, false);
</script>
```

If you don't have direct control over the page being loaded into the InappBrowser, you could inject the code to send the message:

```
inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ 
    code: '\
        document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){\
            var message = {action: "myNativeMethod"};\
            webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message));\
        }, false);\
    '
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer，But this didn't solve my problem。Maybe it’s not clear enough for me to describe。I need to open the remote webApp via InAppBrowser, the webApp can call the local plugin。

Comment: A webapp running in the InappBrowser cannot directly call a local plugin present in the Cordova app - the Webviews are completely separate. The mechanism I have described is the only way a page in the InappBrowser can invoke code in the Cordova app Webview. Unless you load the remote webapp directly into the Cordova Webview, which is a bad idea.

Comment: I modified the underlying code of the 'InAppBrowser' plugin to give it access to other cordova plugins. But you can't get the result of calling the plugin.

Comment: In your way, can the remote webApp call all installed plugins and return the correct callback results remotely?

Comment: The postMessage API is one-directional. If you want to return the plugin result you could use injectScript to insert it into the InappBrowser page.

Comment: I have solved this problem, I modified the InAppBrowser source code and cordova.js code to achieve my needs.

Comment: @DaveAlden in your third snippet (the one with the script tags), I think you mean that code has to write in the called page, if the page is under your control. This is my case. I call an external page and I can edit its code. So, that code is used to send message? And.. how can I include the webkit in my page? Or are there also other ways to send the messages?

Comment: @PieroAlberto the `webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage()` function (and its namespace) is created by the Inappbrower webview so is inherently available to any webpage loaded into it - you don't need to do anything to create it.