# Cordova - ExecuteScript callback when i click submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm currently working with inAppBrowser to open an external web hosted app, I used executeScript and loaded external js to interact with the DOM, is there a way to fire the callback when I click on the submit button?
or a way to access the dom without executeScript?
What I need to do is fire the callback on click event because I need to pass the localStorage before changing the domain.

**index.js**

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
  if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) { 
    navigator.notification.alert('An internet connection is required to continue');
  } else {
    var options = "location=no,hidden=no";
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('extSite', '_blank', options);
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event){
      console.log("il link e' " +event.url);
      if(event.url.startsWith("extSite")){ 
      ref.executeScript({
        file:'extfile'
      });
    }
  });
 }
}
```

**extfile.js**

```
document.getElementById('LoginButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (document.getElementsByName("RememberLogin")[0].checked==true){
        var usr = document.getElementsByName('Username')[0].value;
        var psw = document.getElementsByName('Password')[0].value;
         if ((usr!="") && (psw!="")){
            localStorage.setItem('Username', usr);
            localStorage.setItem('Password', psw);
            alert('data saved');
         }
    }
    else {
        localStorage.removeItem("Username");
        localStorage.removeItem("Password");
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use the postMessage API: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902605/777265)

Comment: Hi Dave, I saw your answers on similar questions, but whit postMessage, when I try to use "webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage" I obtain an error:
"Uncaught reference webkit", moreover, I've already installed the unreleased version of inappbrowser that implements postMessage.

Comment: See [my test project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-test) which references [my test content page](https://dpa99c.github.io/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-test/iab_content/iab.html) - tested & working on Android and iOS

Comment: thank you for your answers, I tried your test project.
If I try to open my site on your project all works, instead, if I try postmessage on my project "webkit is not defined" is what I obtain...
Solutions?

Comment: You need to install the inappbrowser plugin directly from the [github repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) (`v3.1.0-dev`) as the postMessage functionality is not in the latest npm release (`v3.0.0`)

Comment: I solved, Thank You